# Django queryset: how to filter a RawSQL annotation based on a queryset field

Tags: django

Is it possible to do something like this in Django:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    val=RawSQL(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM another_model_table where some_field= %s",
            (a_field_from_MyModel)
        )
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    val=RawSQL(
        """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM another_model_table 
            where some_field=myapp_mymodel.some_field""",
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Todor, that makes sense but I get an error - Django is unhappy with the myapp_mymodel.some_field part - could you explain?

Comment: it should be `table_name.field_name`, by default Django prepends the app name in front of model name for the table name, i.e. MyModel inside MyApp will have a table `myapp_mymodel`. Check you query/database to get the right name.

Comment: forget it it was just a typo, thanks for the answer!